# How to inher variables values from one page to another in java?

Tags: java, oop, variables, inheritance, global-variables

I'm new to java and I'm stuck with this.
I have one BasePage class that contains a "global" List and an int value like this;

```
public class BasePage {
    public int number;
    public List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>;
}
```

Moreover, I've two classes that extend that page;

```
public class ClassA extends BasePage {
   
      public void addStringToList {
            stringList.add("String1");
            number++;
       }

}
```

And other:

```
public class ClassB extends BasePage {
   
      public void addStringToList {
            stringList.add("String2");
            number++;
       } 
}
```

Then, when I access "stringList" and "number" after calling that who classes, the values are not "stacked" in BasPage. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to make everything `static`, but it's a little unclear what your actual goal is.

Comment: Thanks, @RobbyCornelissen, it was related to the use of "static" that was unclear to me. Thanks for your comment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields aren't static, meaning, each and every instance of a `BasePage` object has its own 'version' of it. (and an instance of a `ClassA` **is** a `BasePage` instance as well; `ClassA` extends `BasePage` which means it's a more specific kind of BasePage. It's a BasePage with extra things, in other words).

Thus, when you run:

```
BasePage z = new BasePage();
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB();
```

You have 3 different `number`s and 3 different `stringList`.

You can reduce this down to having just one for the entire VM by making them `static` but **beware**, this is almost universally derided as bad code style: You've created global state, which is hard to test, and makes code hard to read.

A better idea would be to have a separate class such that instances of it represent 'an application', 'a library', 'a ledger', or something similar: A thing that encompasses the idea of 'a whole bunch of BasePage instances'.

This `stringList` variable would then be in the library class, not the book class. Example:

### Bad design

```
public class Book {
    private static int booksInLibrary = 0;
    private String title;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        booksInLibrary++;
    }
}
```

### Good design

```
public class Library {
    private final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public int countBooks() {
        return books.size();
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
    }
}

public class Book {
    private final String title;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```